# Upload a document and display it to the user straight away

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, refinerycms, refinery

Requirement :
I should upload a document (say ppt and pdf) and display it straight away to the User. Note: The ppt and pdf should be displayed like a webpage for viewing

Questions:
1. Is there any out of the box solution for this in Refinery CMS?

2. If Yes, will I be able to try the same in the demo site provided from Refinery CMS? Let me know.

Thanks,